# How to attach images in mailer from active storage association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer, rails-activestorage

In rails 5.2, I have a model using has_many_attached :images.  I would like to send out an email that includes all associated images as attachments.

My mailer method currently looks like:

```
def discrepancy_alert(asset_discrepancy_id, options={})
  @asset_discrepancy = AssetDiscrepancy.find asset_discrepancy_id
  @asset_discrepancy.images.each_with_index do |img,i|
    attachments["img_#{ i }"] = File.read(img)
  end
  mail to: 'noone@gmail.com', subject: "email subject"
end
```

obviously, File.read does not work here because img is not a path, it is a blob.  I have not been able to find any info on this in the docs

## Question One:

Is there a rails method for attaching a blob like this?

## I can use the following instead:

```
@asset_discrepancy.images.each_with_index do |img,i|
  attachments["img_#{ i }"] = img.blob.download
end
```

## Question Two:

the download method could use a log of RAM, is this usage ill advised?

It seems, with the addition of ActiveStorage, that rails mailers would have some new methods for interaction between the two....I have not seen anything in the docs.  All the mailer attachments[] examples use paths to a local file.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind insisting on having them as attached blobs? Having large or many attachments to a file has significant drawbacks as well.

Comment: I didn't actually want to attach the blob (nor, would that be possible).  Just simply trying to attach the image that is accessed via the blob.  I ended up using the download method, which I think is correct...since, after all...the file does need to be downloaded in order to be attached and emailed.

Answer (score 5):

in app/mailers/mailer.rb:

```
if @content.image.attached? 
  @filename = object.id.to_s + object.image.filename.extension_with_delimiter
  if ActiveStorage::Blob.service.respond_to?(:path_for)
    attachments.inline[@filename] = File.read(ActiveStorage::Blob.service.send(:path_for, object.image.key))
  elsif ActiveStorage::Blob.service.respond_to?(:download)
    attachments.inline[@filename] = object.image.download
  end
end
```

in mailer view:

```
if @filename
  image_tag(attachments[@filename].url)
else
  image_tag(attachments['placeholder.png'].url)
end
```

Comment: Beware. This only works if the file is stored locally. It fails for Google Storage or Amazon S3.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the working solution for active storage url in email template. I have seen the images visible in gmail. You can use "rails_blob_url". This works for file stored in aws s3.

mailer.rb

```
....    
@image_url = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_url(blob),
....
```

mailer view file

```
<img src="<%= @image_url %>">
```